# In ansible playbook, need to run script and store that output in remote machine

Tags: ansible

I wrote ansible playbook, to run the script in remote machine and store that o/p in the remote machine only. I have copied that script into remote machine, upto coping is working, but output is not storing in output file and how to know that script is running

```
---
 - hosts: clinet
   remote_user: root
   tasks:
    - name: copy file to remote machine
      copy: src=/etc/ansible/1.py dest=/tmp/1.py mode=777

    - name: execute python script
      command: python /tmp/1.py > /tmp/1.out
```

Comment: You may want to read about `command` and `shell` module difference. Also, please format your question nicely code format option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First register the output into variable and add the content to the file.

```
- name: execute python script
  command: python /tmp/1.py
  register: {{some_var}}

- copy:
    content="{{some_var.stdout}}"
    dest=/path/to/destination/file
```